# Site does not exist error for a2ensite

Tags: apache, apache2, virtualhost

I have `cmsplus.dev` under `/etc/apache2/sites-available` with the following code,

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin master@server.com
    ServerName www.cmsplus.dev
    ServerAlias cmsplus.dev

    DocumentRoot /var/www/cmsplus.dev/public

    LogLevel warn
    ErrorLog /var/www/cmsplus.dev/log/error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/cmsplus.dev/log/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Now when I use `sudo /usr/sbin/a2ensite cmsplus.dev`, I am getting the error,

```
ERROR: Site cmsplus.dev does not exist!
```

My webserver `Apache/2.4.6 (Ubuntu)`

How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 690, accepted):

Solved the issue by adding `.conf` extension to site configuration files.

Apache `a2ensite` results in:

> Error! Site Does Not Exist

Problem; If you found the error while trying to enable a site using:

```
sudo a2ensite example.com
```

but it returns:

> Error: example.com does not exist

`a2ensite` is simply a Perl script that only works with filenames ending `.conf`

Therefore, I have to rename my setting file for `example.com` to `example.com.conf` as might be achieved as follows:

```
mv /etc/apache2/sites-available/example.com /etc/apache2/sites-available/example.com.conf
```

Success

Comment: Weird! This used to work fine without an extension in Ubuntu 12.04 and 12.10.

Comment: Same for me. Like says Guilherme the apache2.conf changed between ubuntu or Apache versions.

Comment: As an alternative I believe you could just edit the apache.conf file. The relevant line is "IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf" Remove the .conf on the end and you'll be back to what worked in 12.04. I think this may be a change Debian made that trickeled into Ubuntu, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Why is this answers 3rd? This is the correct way of doing it.

Comment: I had already given up after changing pretty much everything... I will remember to add the .conf extension from now on...

Comment: I think `.conf` extension Must add to your virtual host file name according to  `apache2` version, As default virtual host for `apache2` (Which used as template to create your own virtual host) under `/etc/apache2/site-available/` Folder called `000-default.conf`.


In my case: `apache2` version is `Server version: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)`

Comment: +1 me if you came from this tutorial https://www.debian-administration.org/article/412/Hosting_multiple_websites_with_Apache2

Comment: Confirming for Ubuntu 12.04 and Apache 2.2.2 that you don't require the .conf extesion for the a2enmod to work correctly.

Comment: I don't know why, but I'd a site config file ending with a `.disabled` extension, just like `subdomain.domain.com.conf.disabled`. Y renamed the file by deleteing the `.disabled` extension and the `a2ensite` command finally worked.

Answer (score 96):

You probably updated your Ubuntu installation and one of the updates included the upgrade of Apache to version 2.4.x

In Apache 2.4.x the vhost configuration files, located in the /etc/apache2/sites-available directory, must have the .conf extension.

Using terminal (mv command), rename all your existing configuration files and add the .conf extension to all of them.

```
mv /etc/apache2/sites-available/cmsplus.dev /etc/apache2/sites-available/cmsplus.dev.conf
```

If you get a "Permission denied" error, then add "sudo " in front of your terminal commands.

You do not need to make any other changes to the configuration files.

Enable the vhost(s):

```
a2ensite cmsplus.dev.conf
```

And then reload Apache:

```
service apache2 reload
```

Your sites should be up and running now.

---

UPDATE: As mentioned [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/upgrading.html), a Linux distribution that you installed changed the configuration to Include *.conf only. Therefore it has nothing to do with Apache 2.2 or 2.4

Comment: Strange, I got the error when I tried to enable a site using a path: "sudo a2ensite /etc/apache2/sites-available/example.com.conf". On the other hand opening a console window within the sites-available directory and running "sudo a2ensite example.com.conf" executed perfectly.

Comment: I also tried within sites available folder and. just worked that ubuntu 20.04

Comment: @MarkLee, the `a2ensite` command doesn't expect a path. Just `sudo a2ensite example.com` should have worked regardless of the directory you were in

Answer (score 28):

There's another good way, just edit the file `apache2.conf` theres a line at the end

> IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf

just remove the `.conf` at the end, like this

> IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*

and restart the server.

(I tried this only in the Ubuntu 13.10, when I updated it.)

Comment: Hmm... I tried this on Ubuntu 14.04 and it didn't work. Adding `.conf` to the config files did, though.

Comment: strange, I had this error when I updated my ubuntu 12.04 to 13.10 (because I substituted unintentionally the apache config files). In the 14.04 update I remembered to not substitute, and I did had any trouble.

Comment: This is really not a good way.  Files under sites-enabled are symlinks to the corresponding files under sites-available and should just be removed to disable the site - that is in fact what a2dissite does  a2ensite correspondingly enables the site.

Answer (score 8):

I just had the same problem. I'd say it has nothing to do with the apache.conf.

a2ensite must have changed - line 532 is the line that enforces the .conf suffix:

```
else {
    $dir    = 'sites';
    $sffx   = '.conf';
    $reload = 'reload';
}
```

If you change it to:

```
else {
    $dir    = 'sites';
    #$sffx   = '.conf';
    $sffx   = '';
    $reload = 'reload';
}
```

...it will work without any suffix.

Of course you wouldn't want to change the a2ensite script, but changing the conf file's suffix is the correct way.

It's probably just a way of enforcing the ".conf"-suffix.

Comment: See this question too: http://askubuntu.com/questions/362682/403-error-after-upgrading-to-apache2-4

Answer (score 8):

So .. 
quickest way is rename site config names ending in ".conf"

```
mv /etc/apache2/sites-available/mysite /etc/apache2/sites-available/mysite.conf

a2ensite mysite.conf
```

other notes on previous comments:

- IncludeOptional wasn't introduced until apache 2.36 - making change above followed by restart on 2.2 will leave your server down!
- also, version 2.2 a2ensite can't be hacked as described

as well, since your sites-available file is actually a configuration file, it should be named that way anyway..

---

In general *do not* restart services  (webservers are one type of service):

- folks can't find them if they are not running! Think linux not MS Windows..

Servers can run for many years - live update, reload config, etc.

The cloud doesn't mean you have to restart to load a configuration file.

- When changing configuration of a service use "reload" not "restart".
- restart stops the service then starts service - if there is a any problem in your change to the config, the service *will not* restart.
- reload will give an error but the service never shuts down giving you a chance to fix the config error which could only be bad syntax.

debian or ubunto [service-name for this thread is apache2]

```
service {service-name} {start} {stop} {reload} ..
```

other os's left as an excersize for the reader.

Answer (score 6):

Worked after I added `.conf` to the configuration file

Answer (score 6):

I realise that's not the case here but it might help someone.

Double-check you didn't create the conf file in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled by mistake. You get the same error.

Comment: Where should the file be?

Comment: @LucasSteffen /etc/apache2/sites-available. From memory, the one in  sites-enabled is created automatically

Comment: There are **so many** online "guides" that get this wrong.

Answer (score 3):

I have just upgraded the Ubuntu Server version from 12.04 LTS to 14.04 LTS.

Indeed, as said above, the .conf extension to Apache 2.4.x is needed to the websites vhost files that resides on sites-available directory.

Before read this question I did not have a clue what was going on with the server.

Pretty nice solution.

Just summarizing I did the following steps on Terminal:

1) Access sites-enabled folder

```
$ cd /etc/apache2/sites-enabled
```

2) Because the command a2dissite will not work with deprecated files (without .conf) remove the old website files that was published

```
$ sudo rm <my-old-website-without-.conf>
```

3) Rename the website vhost files changing its extension adding .conf to the end

```
$ sudo mv /etc/apache2/sites-available/mywebsite /etc/apache2/sites-available/mywebsite.conf
```

4) Republish the new and correct vhost file

```
$ sudo a2ensite mywebsite.conf
```

5) Check the website on browser and have fun! :)

Comment: Thanks, that's the only thing that did it for me: cleaning sites-enabled before re-enabling them.

Answer (score 2):

In my case with Ubuntu 14.04.3 and Apache 2.4.7, the problem was that I copied site1.conf to make site2.conf available, and by copying, something happend and I could not a2ensite site2.conf with the error described in thread.

The solution for me, was to rename site2.conf to site2 and then again rename site2 to site2.conf. After that I was able to a2ensite site2.conf.

Comment: yes, this is working in Ubuntu 20. `cd /etc/apache2/sites-available`, `mv mysite.conf mysite && mv mysite mysite.conf`. Then `a2ensite mysite.conf` shows `Enabling site mysite`. Then we can `systemctl start apache2` or `systemctl reload apache2`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, because of I tried to use absolute path.

```
 sudo a2ensite /etc/apache2/sites-available/test.conf
```

instead just run

```
 sudo a2ensite test.conf
```

it will work after

```
sudo systemctl reload apache2
```

Answer (score -2):

Try like this..

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin master@server.com
    ServerName www.cmsplus.dev
    ServerAlias cmsplus.dev

    DocumentRoot /var/www/cmsplus.dev/public

    LogLevel warn
    ErrorLog /var/www/cmsplus.dev/log/error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/cmsplus.dev/log/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

and add entry in /etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1 www.cmsplus.dev
```

restart apache..

Comment: Now it's giving me the default ``It works`` page instead of the settings.

Comment: Do you have multiple virtual hosts configuration? Can you post whole file content?

Comment: Thanks, solved this issue by just adding ``.conf`` extension to these site configuration files.