# What is the difference between the 'sites-enabled' and 'sites-available' directory?

Tags: apache2, webserver, ubuntu-12.04

What is use of these two directories in Apache 2 and how can we do it?

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/83508/purpose-of-debian-sites-available-and-sites-enabled-dirs

Answer (score 132):

The difference is that virtual sites listed in the `sites-enabled` directory are served by Apache. In the `sites-available` directory there are the virtual sites that exist on your server, but people can't access them because they are not **enabled** yet.

> **sites-available:** this directory has configuration files for Apache 2 Virtual Hosts. Virtual Hosts allow Apache 2 to be configured for
> multiple sites that have separate configurations.
>
> **sites-enabled:** like mods-enabled, **sites-enabled contains symlinks to
> the /etc/apache2/sites-available directory**. Similarly when a
> configuration file in sites-available is symlinked, the site
> configured by it will be active once Apache2 is restarted.

See *https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/httpd.html*.

Comment: Should I edit files in **sites-enabled** or in **sites-available** ?

Comment: @user3448600 you should edit files in sites-available

Comment: if those are symlinks, it doesn't matter which one you edit

Comment: @Buksy Actually it matters, if you are using nano editor. See my answer for details.

Comment: The links seems to be dead.

Comment: The link is effectively broken (redirects to a generic page, *[Ubuntu Server Guide](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs)*).

Answer (score 119):

### Important information

**If you are still using sites-available/sites-enabled pattern**, you should edit files **only** in the `sites-available` directory.

**Never** edit files inside the `sites-enabled` directory. Otherwise you can have problems if your editor runs out of memory or, for any reason, it receives a [SIGHUP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal_(IPC)#POSIX_signals) or [SIGTERM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal_(IPC)#POSIX_signals).

For example: if you are using [nano](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_nano) to edit the file `sites-enabled/default` and it runs out of memory or, for any reason, it receives a SIGHUP or SIGTERM, then nano will create an emergency file called `default.save`, inside the `sites-enabled` directory.

So, there will be an extra file inside the `sites-enabled` directory. That will prevent Apache or [nginx](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nginx) from starting. If your site was working, it will not be any more. You will have a hard time until you find out, in the logs, something related to the `default.save` file and, then, remove it.

In the example above, if you were editing the file inside the `sites-available` directory, nothing bad would have happened. The file `sites-available/default.save` would have been created, but it wouldn't do any harm inside the `sites-available` directory.

---

### Update

The `sites-enabled/site-available` pattern is deprecated, according to [The Complete NGINX Cookbook](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/nginx-cookbook/9781492049098/ch01.html) in NGINX [official site](https://www.nginx.com/).

> The /etc/nginx/conf.d/ directory contains the default HTTP server
> configuration file. Files in this directory ending in .conf are
> included in the top-level http block from within the /etc/
> nginx/nginx.conf file. It’s best practice to utilize include state‐
> ments and organize your configuration in this way to keep your
> configuration files concise. In some package repositories, this folder
> is named sites-enabled, and configuration files are linked from a
> folder named site-available; this convention is deprecated.

**Instead of using `sites-enabled/site-available` pattern, just add a your-site.conf under the /etc/nginx/conf.d folder.**

Comment: Well, you need to restart your webserver anyway in order for the action to take effect, thus, even if the editor added that extra file, your webserver will ignore it unless you restart the webserver.

Comment: @shamaseen Once you have the extra file, you won't be able to star/restart the webserver whenever you need. That is the problem.

Answer (score 13):

You configure your site `mysite` by creating or editing the file `mysite.conf` in `sites-available` (you can also configure several sites in the same *.conf* file, if you prefer).

After this, for publishing the site you must create the correspondent symlink in folder `sites-enabled`. In Ubuntu you can do it like this:

`a2ensite mysite` (with `sudo`, if necessary; and without the final .conf)

And then you must reload Apache:

```
sudo service apache2 reload
```

Later, if you want to modify the configuration, you only touch the `mysite.conf` file in `sites_available`. Changes apply automatically in `sites_enabled`, through the symbolic link. Just remember to reload Apache.