# Nginx - Do I really need sites-available and sites-enabled folders?

Tags: nginx

I noticed my install of nginx has three folders called

```
etc/nginx/sites-available
etc/nginx/sites-enabled
etc/nginx/conf.d
```

Do I really need these if I just want to work directly in the `etc/nginx/nginx.conf` file and remove the `include` lines that include these items in `nginx.conf`? Are these directories used for anything else that would mess things up if I delete them?

Comment: Although already answered, I see this a lot and often wonder myself, why bother with this structure? This is a Debian (i.e. Ubuntu) convention. In other non-Debian distributions you will not find `sites-available/enabled` which is to closely mimic the way Apache does things. To say this is a best practice is arguable. Plenty of good reads around behind this topic e.g. https://serverfault.com/a/870709

Comment: Note [Arun's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64438763/1889273) is the most up to date and IMHO should be the accepted answer in 2021.

Comment: As noted above, according to the official (and freely available) [NGINX Cookbook](https://www.nginx.com/resources/library/complete-nginx-cookbook/) from 2022 states that the `sites-enable` & `sites-available` "_convention is deprecated_". [Arun's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64438763/1889273) has the complete quote, along with the suggestion of what to use instead.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

No, they are not needed if you define your server blocks properly in nginx.conf, but it's highly suggested. As you noticed, they are only used because of the `include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;` in nginx.conf.

For curiosity, is there a reason why you do not want to use them? They are very useful; easier to add new sites, disabling sites, etc. Rather than having one large config file. This is a kind of a best practice of nginx folder layout.

Comment: I guess because I like to keep things simple. I am not hosting a ton of sites. Only a couple.

Answer (score 21):

As the (freely available) [NGINX Cookbook](https://www.nginx.com/resources/library/complete-nginx-cookbook/) states under section "***1.5 Key Files, Directories, and Commands***":

> The `/etc/nginx/conf.d/` directory contains the default HTTP
> server configuration file. Files in this directory ending in `.conf`
> are included in the top-level `http` block from within the `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` file. It’s best practice to utilize `include` statements and organize your configuration in this way to keep your
> configuration files concise.
>
> In some package repositories, this
> folder is named `sites-enabled`, and configuration files are linked
> from a folder named `site-available`; this convention is **deprecated**.

With that said, I couldn't find any deprecation notice in the [NGINX docs](https://docs.nginx.com/). As the author also carefully points out, this convention may only be a thing "*in some package repositories*", and not something universal. (See @Robin's comment below, for example.) [This NGINX sub-reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/nginx/comments/re8ksm/why_is_sitesenabled_and_sitesavailable_deprecated/) was also elucidating.

Comment: I was looking for this EXACT answer - thank you.

Comment: In other words, according to this, add a `your-site.conf` under the `/etc/nginx./conf.d` folder, instead of using the deprected `sites-enabled/site-available` pattern.

Comment: On CentOS 7 at the time of writing despite nginx being installed, conf.d is empty and only nginx.conf exists in /etc/nginx.

Answer (score 17):

**Important information:**

If you opt for the sites-enabled/sites-available pattern, make sure to exclusively modify files in the sites-available directory.

**Never** edit files inside the `sites-enabled` directory, otherwise you can have problems if your editor runs out of memory or, for any reason, it receives a SIGHUP or SIGTERM.

For example: if you are using `nano` to edit the file `sites-enabled/default` and it runs out of memory or, for any reason, it receives a SIGHUP or SIGTERM, then `nano` will create an emergency file called `default.save`, inside the `sites-enabled` directory. So, there will be an extra file inside the `sites-enabled` directory. That will prevent Apache or NGINX to start. If your site was working, it will not be anymore. You will have a hard time until you find out, in the logs, something related to the `default.save` file and, then, remove it.

In the example above, if you were editing the file inside the `sites-available` directory, nothing bad would have happened. The file `sites-available/default.save` would have been created, but it wouldn't do any harm inside the `sites-available` directory.

Comment: He also said this here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21812360/what-is-the-difference-between-sites-enabled-and-sites-available-directory/41568701#41568701

Answer (score 1):

It is not a must, but a best practise if you host more than one sites on your box.

It will be easier to manage by keep http context and common directives (such as ssl_dhparam, ssl_ciphers, or even gzip settings, etc.) on the nginx.conf so that it applied across all sites.

Keep site-specific server context (such as ssl-certificate, location directives, etc.) at etc/nginx/sites-available/ and name the configuration file as your-domain.conf. The file in etc/nginx/sites-enabled can be just a link to the file to the etc/nginx/sites-available.