# How do I set up an nginx conf with a subdomain and reverse_proxy and NO use of sites-enabled?

Tags: nginx, subdomain, reverse-proxy

I've read that it's not necessary to use [`sites-enabled`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41303885/nginx-do-i-really-need-sites-available-and-sites-enabled-folders), and even seen it [suggested not to use](https://serverfault.com/a/870709/547377).

In any case, its merit is not part of the question (so please consider that discussion off topic).

What I'm trying to do is set up an absolutely barebones basic `nginx.conf` file which does some super basic use case stuff: various forms of redirection.

By my understanding, this conf should be enough:

```
http {
  # default server
  server {
    root /var/www/html/production-site;

    # reverse proxy for external blog, makes example.com/blog display the blog.  helps with SEO.
    location /blog/ {
      proxy_pass https://example.some-external-blog.com/;
    }
  }

  # dev server
  server {
    server_name dev.example.com;
    root /var/www/html/dev-site;
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, my example doesn't work.  The proxy bit works, but subdomains don't seem to.  I don't honestly believe that server_name does anything at this point.

**So, how does one write a simple (no extras) nginx.conf file which will exemplify these super trivial functionalities (subdomains and reverse proxies)?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your config at my sandbox VM. nginx refuses to start, and when I run `nginx -t` command (which is always a good idea after significant configuration change), it says:

```
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: [emerg] no "events" section in configuration
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

So I've added `events {}` line to the config. After that nginx successfuly starts and all is working as expected.

Another thing that I wouldn't skip is including `mime.types` file. So final minimal configuration would look as follows:

```
events {}

http {
  include mime.types;

  # default server
  server {
    root /var/www/html/production-site;

    # reverse proxy for external blog, makes example.com/blog display the blog.  helps with SEO.
    location /blog/ {
      proxy_pass https://example.some-external-blog.com/;
    }
  }

  # dev server
  server {
    server_name dev.example.com;
    root /var/www/html/dev-site;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  By having a minimal config example, it is much easier to understand what factors -- having started with the much less minimal default config -- are contributing to the system.