# Bringing up Nginx server with update its config and getting "default.conf is not a file or does not exist"

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, amazon-eks

I am trying to deploy an nginx server in Kubernetes. I am just trying to get a server up and look at it through a loadbalancer while also being able to modify the nginx config.

Using the below configuration I can not get the nginx webserver pod to start.

```
$ kubectl get pods
NAME                     READY   STATUS   RESTARTS   AGE
nginx-696c84fd7b-dr9hv   0/1     Error    3          55s
```

looking at the pod log I get the following:

```
$ kubectl logs nginx-696c84fd7b-dr9hv
/docker-entrypoint.sh: /docker-entrypoint.d/ is not empty, will attempt to perform configuration
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Looking for shell scripts in /docker-entrypoint.d/
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh
10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf is not a file or does not exist, exiting
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/20-envsubst-on-templates.sh
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Configuration complete; ready for start up
2020/06/30 22:52:03 [emerg] 1#1: no "events" section in configuration
nginx: [emerg] no "events" section in configuration
```

I assume I am doing something wrong with the config. Do I need to change it to overwrite the or create the default.conf?

FYI - This is coming up in an AWS EKS cluster.

Here is the entire yaml I am launching using "kubectl create -f nginx_deployment.yaml":

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: nginx-conf
data:
  nginx.conf: |
    http {
      server {
          location / {
              return 200 'Eureka!!';
              add_header Content-Type text/plain;
          }
      }
    }
---
apiVersion: apps/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /etc/nginx # mount nginx-conf volumn to /etc/nginx
          readOnly: true
          name: nginx-conf
      volumes:
      - name: nginx-conf
        configMap:
          name: nginx-conf # place ConfigMap `nginx-conf` on /etc/nginx
          items:
            - key: nginx.conf
              path: nginx.conf
      - name: log
        emptyDir: {}

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 80
  selector:
    app: nginx
```

I tried replacing ir to be default.conf but then it just hangs forever in the "ContainerCreaing" state.

Changes made in the deployment section -

```
apiVersion: apps/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /etc/nginx/conf.d # mount nginx-conf volumn to /etc/nginx
          readOnly: true
          name: nginx-conf
      volumes:
      - name: nginx-conf
        configMap:
          name: nginx-conf # place ConfigMap `nginx-conf` on /etc/nginx
          items:
            - key: default.conf
              path: default.conf
      - name: log
        emptyDir: {}
```

Comment: Could you elaborate what you want to achieve? Do you want to deploy [Nginx Deployment](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/) like from the docs? Or maybe you want to use [Nginx Ingress Controller](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/) ? If you want Nginx to create `LoadBalancer` I guess you are thinking about `Nginx Ingress controller`. Please specify.

Comment: `events { ... }` block is required for nginx config, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58867097/how-do-i-set-up-an-nginx-conf-with-a-subdomain-and-reverse-proxy-and-no-use-of-s) Q/A for minimalistic nginx config example.