# Default Apache displaying instead of homepage

Tags: django, apache, web-deployment, linode

I am having issues trying to deploy my site,.I am still new in both Django , their is a tutorial I have been following on how to deploy the site, Everything works fine except it renders the default Apache page instead of my site when I restart the server.

Here is my project directory

```html
Alias /static /home/brian/src/static
  <Directory /home/brian/src/static>
    Require all granted
  </Directory>

  Alias /media /home/brian/src/media
  <Directory /home/brian/src/media>
    Require all granted
  </Directory>

  <Directory /home/brian/src/src>
    <Files wsgi.py>
      Require all granted
    </Files>
  </Directory>

  WSGIScriptAlias / /home/brian/src/src/wsgi.py
  WSGIDaemonProcess django_app python-path=/home/brian/src python-home=/home/brian/src/venv
  WSGIProcessGroup django_app
```

Comment: is `django_app` in `WSGIDaemonProcess` the domain name of your site?

Comment: Did you read [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/#using-mod-wsgi-daemon-mode)? you're missing the `process-group` directive in your `WSGIScriptAlias`.

Comment: @dirkgroten django_app is just a process,it snot my domain name

Comment: the fact that it's showing the apache home page shows that it's not reaching this part of your configuration at all. Is this inside of a `<VirtualHost *:80>` tag with the `ServerName` set to the domain?

Comment: Its in my ln /etc/apache2/sites-available/blog.conf directory aand yes its within the <VirtualHost *:80> tag

Comment: I dont have my servername set,I  was following it from a tutorial so I followed what he did

Comment: I think sites-available isn't enough, you need to symlink to it in sites-enabled

Comment: can you kindly show me how to go abut this or provide a link,I am new here

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21812360/what-is-the-difference-between-sites-enabled-and-sites-available-directory